# C# for each property get both value and name

Tags: c#, json, linq

I'm sending a JSON object through PUT from angularJS to c#, which has a property name and a value.

I'm trying to loop for each property and read both name and the value, but it fails. I have succeed to read only the name or only the value though with the below code:

```
Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JObject cbpcs = pricestopsale.cbPricegroups;
foreach (string pricegroupInfo in cbpcs.Properties().Select(p => p.Value).ToList())
{
   // I want to be able to do something like this inside here
   if(pricegroupInfo.Value == "Something") {
     // do stuff
   }
}
```

In my above example pricegroupInfo has the value, if i change `.Select(p => p.Name).ToList())` i get the name of the property.

What can I do if i want to get both name and value inside my loop ?

Update 1: The property Name is unknown to me, it's generated dynamically so I dont know in advance the property name.

Update 2: I want to be able to compare the value and the name as a string inside the loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using an anonymous object in the select.

```
Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JObject cbpcs = pricestopsale.cbPricegroups;
foreach (var pricegroupInfo in cbpcs.Properties().Select(p => new { p.Value, p.Name }).ToList())
{
    // read the properties like this
    var value = pricegroupInfo.Value;
    var name = pricegroupInfo.Name;

    if(pricegroupInfo.Value.ToObject<string>() == "foo")
    {
        Console.WriteLine("this is true");
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you please also add how i'll read the name and value inside the loop ?

Comment: I tried, but when i do if(value.ToString == "True") (true is not bollean) i get error , even without .ToString. How can I check if value == "Something"?

Comment: This happens because your Value and Name properties are of type "JValue" so you need to convert them. Updated the code again.

Answer (score 1):

[Reference: **JObject.Properties Method**](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/M_Newtonsoft_Json_Linq_JObject_Properties.htm)

```
Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JObject cbpcs = pricestopsale.cbPricegroups;
foreach (var pricegroupInfo in cbpcs.Properties())
{
    if(pricegroupInfo.Name == "propName"     // your property name
       &&  pricegroupInfo.Value.ToString() == "something") {   // your value

       // do stuff
    }
}
```

As you can see, it returns `IEnumerable<JProperty>` which use can iterate and make use of to get property `Name` and `Value`

Comment: Can you please add a string comparison  to your answer? eg. if(pricegroupInfo.Select(p => p.Key) == "Something") { }

Comment: @SimosFasouliotis - updated as per your comment, didn't see your updated question

Comment: It gives an error, that i was not able to copy/paste. https://ibb.co/eFbjxc

Comment: @SimosFasouliotis - updated answer. now it will work

Comment: I have already accepted another answer, but your answer works too so i'm Upvoting it. Many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
foreach(var prop in cbpcs.GetType().GetProperties()) {
   Console.WriteLine("{0}={1}", prop.Name, prop.GetValue(foo, null));}
```

Comment: The property Name is unknown to me, it's generated dynamically so I dont know in advance the property name. So i cannot do GetValue(foo), sorry I didnt mention earlier. Can you update your code please?